# Fantasy anime where girls transform into different things to help others

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime a few years ago as of 2020. It’s about a few girls (I think 3) that get given a power by a little creature (actually an exiled prince from another world). The power is they can transform into different versions of themselves to help others.

The main girl (I think has pink hair) has a crush on a guy (the exiled prince's brother) that turns out to basically be evil.

The exiled prince needs the girls to collect love or something to help save his land from darkness / the queen of the land. And some point the exiled prince starts to fall in love with the main girl.

It’s sort of like a magical girl anime I suppose? The girls can transform into things like flight attendants, teachers and things like that. Though they do keep features like their hair and eye colour. The brother of the exiled prince has a girl with him as well that I think was in love with the exiled prince?

I'm pretty sure I watched this series on YouTube as well.

Comment: This is definitely some flavour of magical girl anime. If I had more time, I'd take a look.

Comment: @DarkHeart ID questions are off-topic on Anime.SE. In fact, OP asked this there initially and was correctly redirected here.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Apologies - thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How long ago did you watch it? Meanwhile, while you wait for an answer check the anime and manga list here: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PinkHeroine

Comment: @jo1storm I'm not completely sure but I'm confident it was at least a year ago.

Comment: Did the pink haired girl have long or short hair? How big was the "team" ? Because this is very old anime and the main character transforms into nurse, police officer, stewardess etc Called  Magical Princess Minky Momo, has pet sidekicks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFPZ1lrykbI 

Other possibility is Tokyo Mew Mew. Also has pink hair. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXRqBVkbE7Y

Comment: @jo1storm No, sadly it is not either of those. The team i'd say was 3 girls in my memory. Her hair was short ish but darker then minky momo's. I believe she might of wore her hair in pigtails?

Comment: What did the little creature look like? This could be one of the Pretty Cure anime (HUGtto?), but not sure.

Comment: @Kitkat Im not completely sure. But i do know that there was only 1 creature. And ofcourse that its a guy.

Answer (score 4):

It's called *[Flowering Heart](https://flowering-heart.fandom.com/wiki/)* took me almost an hour to find the name

> Flowering Heart focuses on Ari Jin and her friends Suha Woo and Min Sunwoo, who race against time to save the Flowering Kingdom, collecting as much Hopeful Energy as they can on Earth. To do so, they are given magical devices with which to transform into older versions of themselves and do good deeds.

And for the other details:

Princes on opposite sides? Check.

Each Prince has at least one girl on their side? Also check.

[Good Prince](https://flowering-heart.fandom.com/wiki/Chess) can transform into an animal-thing? Yep.

Queen making the princes' homeworld bad? Also check.

### Opening

Comment: Hi, can you provide some details from the anime about how they fit this question? Maybe how some of the plot details fit what was asked in the question?